# Excel column separation of data in single cell

Tags: excel

I have copy and pasted data into an Excel worksheet that includes each column's value in the first cell only. How can I separate these into their own cells for later calculations without manually doing 1 at a time, since there are 1,200+ cell values. I have included a screenshot of my current issue.

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: [Text to Columns.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7)

Comment: You go to `Data`>>`Text To Columns` and choose `Fixed Width`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

You can us Data / Text To Columns and split either on fixed width or you can use a space as the delimeter and tell it to treat multiple as single.

You could use a formula using the mid function and trim functions to split out that way.

You could use code using the split function.

SO isn't a volunteer coding site however, it's a learning site so give one of these ideas a go and if you get stuck post back with an example of what you have tried and we will explain what went wrong.